# Suppress convergence message in nnet multinom function in R

Tags: r, knitr, nnet

I am using knitr in R to produce a document of model outputs.  I have suppressed messages and warnings in my code chunk.  But I still get the convergence messages. I have looked for settings in the net package and in the multinom function. Does anybody know how to suppress them?  I have looked on SO and on the internet.  Someone asked a question in 2006 but I can't get the answer returned (and I don't know if it relevant today).

I am running many models in a loop, so it gets verbose very quickly.  This also means that I can't **easily** put the model runs in a different chunk from the output because I am printing tables in each loop.  An example of the output I am trying to suppress is below:

`# weights:  10 (4 variable)
initial  value 2454.392816 
iter  10 value 2175.558042
iter  10 value 2175.558039
final  value 2175.558039 
converged`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I finally found a function argument called "trace" in the nnet function.  Its default is TRUE, and when set to "FALSE" the messages stop.  I am guessing that nnet is called by multinom.  Thank goodness for the ... in R so I could pass a function argument through.

Hopefully this will help someone else.  I didn't mean to answer my own question (but I hope that is ok).

Comment: apparently I need to wait 2 days until I can accept my own answer.

Comment: Actually I found trace before seeing your answer but it says
"switch for tracing optimization. Default TRUE."
Which I thought was something else. R, its packages and documentations are so painful.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/nnet.pdf